# How to get GA data without invoking the browser for asking login and access permission

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-oauth

I am currently working in google analytics. I was able to get it working in eclipse, using tomcat server. while running the application to get the pageviews of my site i am been asked for login and access token permission in my system's default browser. after i provide these details i am getting the analytics displayed via google Oauth2 API's.

Now my question is i want to get these data in a public server which doesn't allow browser UI's. so could any body provide some answers for getting the access token for analytics using plain java like URL connection object.

**Possible Solution**
1 Possible solution got:
Used service login email and key file. which is used to get the auth credentials. This can be generated in google api console where we will be adding the google api's to be used in our projects.